# PHP & JSON not showing any results

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP code, which prints out the results shown in this link:   http://www.visitrack.co.uk/testdata2.php

```
$json = "http://api.duedil.com/sandbox/v2/company/03977902.json fields=get_all&api_key=***";
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);
var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile,true));
```

What i am trying to do is split the results in to individual php variables.  The code below is my attempt, however it doesn't return an error or any results.

```
 $url="http://api.duedil.com/sandbox/v2/company/03977902.json?fields=get_all&api_key=2gwhy5py2zfdzpnf3ev3dsjs";
 $json = file_get_contents($url); $response = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 echo $requestId->Response->id->value;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain why.

Comment: @Cummander - It's not my downvote, but the explanation of the second parameter is in the function signature. Why explicitly pass a `true` value when you don't know what it does?

Comment: The `var_dump` shows exactly what it is, an array, so you access it like an array and not like an object.

Comment: The user clearly does not have the expertise yet - however, that does not make his question less valid or worthy. Therefore i equalised the downvote.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov I think it shows a lack of research effort, but feel free to disagree :-)

Comment: You may be right. Then again what good is research when you cannot understand it?

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the second parameter for `json_decode()` to true. This will result in an associative array. Don't pass anything there (because it is false by default). You can read all about it in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

> json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false ])

Basically, your method of using `->` is how you would access it in the form of an object.

```
$foo->bar
```

In an associative array, this would look like -

```
$foo['bar']
```